# Suppress limits while creating ad accounts in business manager

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I have business account and 2 ad accounts. When i try to create third ad account, I am getting following error.

```
You have exceeded the number of allowed ad accounts for your Business Manager at this time.
```

and

```
(#10) You do not have permission to perform this action. This action requires that you can MODIFY_AD_ACCOUNTS for this business account.
```

As per Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account, We have to use userpermissions then we can avoid this error.

But user permissions does not work while creating ad account in business manager. It is working fine in updating ad account. Following code, I am using.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/'.$associative_arr['businessId'].'/adaccount/userpermissions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);               
curl_close ($ch);
```

Any suggestion how can i use user permission while creating ad account so that i can suppress ad account limit issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Apply to further Access Level **for your app**.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

> - Development: Try the API and test apps on the Facebook platform.
> - Basic: Further test, iterate, build an app with up to 25 external accounts.
> - Standard: Use unlimited accounts to scale your business, and be
>     nominated to become a Facebook Marketing Partner.

Comment: I already have all access levels like ads management basic access, business_management and standard access

Comment: How are you trying to create ad accounts?

Comment: Does the user related to the access token have Admin Role in Business Manager?

Comment: He is my customer that is accessing my app using his facebook account and trying to create ad account.

Comment: @Jass Hi, Were you able figure out this issue? My scenario kinda same but no clue.